# How do I extract the call to setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a bunch of button functions that merely toasts the label on the button.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.button1.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,binding.button1.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.button2.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,binding.button2.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.button3.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,binding.button3.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    binding.button4.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,binding.button4.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I would like to replace these with a single val or fun that extracts all of that Toast code so that I can just use something like

```
fun toastLabel( button : MyButton ) {
    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,button.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

binding.button1.setOnClickListener( toastLabel( binding.button1 ) )
```

or

```
val toastLabel : View.OnClickListener = { button : McButton2 ->
        Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,button.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Neither of those even compile. What's the right syntax to do that?

Comment: You replaced the lambda braces with parentheses so it no longer works. You can only use parentheses if you are passing a functional reference or an actual OnClickListener instance as your argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extract it like this

```kotlin
fun toastLabel(label: String):  View.OnClickListener = View.OnClickListener { 
   Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,label, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

// use it like this
binding.button1.apply { 
    setOnClickListener(toastLabel(this.getLabel()))
}
binding.button2.apply { 
    setOnClickListener(toastLabel(this.getLabel()))
}
...
```

Comment: This one works without modification, but the improvement below is a little slicker. Ill accept it as the answer because it does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's simpler like this:

```
fun toastLabel( button : MyButton ) {
  binding.button.setOnClickListener{
    Toast.makeText(activity?.applicationContext,button.getLabel(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
  }
}
```

call function:

```
toastLabel( binding.button1 )
```

Comment: This one works but only if I take the binding out of the toastLabel function. And its less boilerplate than the above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
val showToast: ((String) -> Unit) = {
    Toast.makeText(this, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

button.setOnClickListener {
   showToast.invoke(label)
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: For this one I had to change this to context because this isnt a context within onViewCreated. But it failed again with label. What is that?